# How to avoid code repetition initializing final properties?

Tags: java, constructor, final

```
public class Code{

//many properties
//...

final String NEWLINE;// ohh a final property!

void creation() //this method is for avoid repetition of code
{        

    //final initialization can't be put here =(

    Source= new StringBuffer();

   //many other commons new's ..
   //...
}

Code()
{
    NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    creation();
}

Code(String name, int numberr)
{
    NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
    creation();

    name=new Someting(name);
    number = new Magic(number);
}
```

}

Comment: +1 for "// ohh a final property!" and a useful Q overall :)

Comment: Why is your NEWLINE an instance variable? I would declare something like this static. I doubt line.separator would change within the lifetime of the JVM instance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is your code with 4 different ways of initializing final variables.

1. inline
2. anonymous initializer block
3. initialized in the constructor
4. calling the default constructor explicitly

The resulting output is shown below.

```
public class Code {

    // many properties
    private String name;
    private String number;
    // ...

    // 1.
    final String NEWLINE_1 = "1" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    final String NEWLINE_2;
    final String NEWLINE_3;

    // 2.
    {
        System.out.println("initializer block invoked before Constructor");

        NEWLINE_2 = "2" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
        // final initialization CAN be put here =(

        // Source = new StringBuffer();

        // many other commons new's ..
        // ...
    }

    Code() {
        System.out.println("default constructor");
        // NEWLINE_1 = "error";     can't do this
        // NEWLINE_2 = "error";     can't do this

        // 3.
        NEWLINE_3 = "3" + System.getProperty("line.separator");
    }

    Code(String name, int number) {
        // 4.
        this();
        System.out.println("constructor(name, number)");

        name = new String("Someting(name)");
        this.number = new String("Magic(number)");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Code code_1 = new Code();
        System.out.println(code_1.NEWLINE_1 + ":" + code_1.NEWLINE_2 + ":" + code_1.NEWLINE_3);

        Code code_2 = new Code("crowne", 2);
        System.out.println(code_2.NEWLINE_1 + ":" + code_2.NEWLINE_2 + ":" + code_2.NEWLINE_3);
    }
}
```

---

```
initializer block invoked before Constructor
default constructor
1
:2
:3

initializer block invoked before Constructor
default constructor
constructor(name, number)
1
:2
:3
```

Answer (score 6):

All initializers are added by the compiler to the beginning of each constructor. This includes:

- instance variable initialization
- initialization blocks `{ .. }`

So you don't have to include this everywhere just place it either as an instance-variable initialization:

```
private final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

or in initialization block:

```
{
     NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

Of course, in this precise example, you should make the field `static`.

Answer (score 3):

Just do:

```
final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

See: [JLS 8.3.2. Initialization of Fields](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/classes.html#8.3.2).

See also: [JLS 12.5 Creation of New Class Instances](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/third_edition/html/execution.html#12.5) for execution order.

Comment: When would be that line executed? 
at creation of first object automatically?

Comment: This field should be static anyway, but that's beside the point.

Answer (score 1):

If they are being initialized the same way every time, you can put the code outside of the constructors.  Java allows you to do:

```
final String NEWLINE = System.getProperty("line.separator");
```

You can also have all constructors other than the no-argument one call the no-argument constructor.  For example:

```
Code(String name, int number)
{
    this();

    name=new Someting(name);
    number = new Magic(number);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more, if the initialization is complex and you must do it during construction, provide a static method the returns the result, as in:

```
Code()
{
    NEWLINE = newLineValue();
    creation();
}

Code(String name, int number)
{
    NEWLINE = newLineValue();
    creation();

    name = new Something(name);
    number = new Magic(number);
}

private static String newLineValue()
{
    return System.getProperty("line.separator");
}
```

In this case, `newLineValue()` is trivial so I wouldn't use it here, but if this actually had a significant amount of work then it could be useful. You can also pass in parameters from the constructor.